# what is the faster way to update a table contains around 10million records?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have to update one table which contains 10 million records(size 84 GB) and which gets feed from many systems on real time basis.

I have to extend the size of a column from 3 char to 5 char because all the new data coming will be of 5 char for this particular field.

Do I need reindex the table to make this change faster?

Do I need to stop the cron jobs which feeds this table during the update activity?

some clarifications on the above:

I would use this query to alter the column:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY cloumnname char(5)
```

we use Oracle Database.

Here are my questions:

- Do I need to stop all the daily cron jobs before making this change in production?
- Will dropping the existing indexes and disabling triggers make it faster?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? If anything, reindexing is going to take more time, not less.

Comment: if you are changing column datatype , it would be a very expensive query, i guess is it what u mean by update ?

Comment: SQL server? MySql? Postgres? I wouldn't recommend doing anything until you've run ***your own tests*** on a non critical system.

Comment: consider creating a new table with the desired schema and writing to that before creating indexes

Comment: Adding additional column is quicker than modifying existing column, you can rename the column name, Also you would need to drop all constraints and re-enable after process completion . It is also ideal to stop any update activity during the whole process

Comment: Well it took sql server 39 secs on my table with 1 million rows to alter an varchar column

Comment: The lack of information in your question is leading to speculation that won't help you one bit. Ask a better question with more information after you've tried something yourself.

Comment: A couple of red flags: 1) You mention "update" when you appear to mean "alter". Those are 2 very different things with very different implications. 2) You may not be using the right datatype for your column (char vs varchar or n-types). And upgrade from 3 to 5 could easily become another update from 5 to 10 in a few months. Don't look at what you need right now but what you need in the forseeable future. Avoid this problem later. >>> And with 10M records, you are running a very serious risk of borking a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

TL;TR: change it to `varchar2(5)`, don't stick with `char`

---

Using `char()` was a bad idea to begin with. Due to the fact that `char` values are padded to the defined length, Oracle indeed needs to rewrite the table in order to be able to increase the size. The `char` data type has no advantage whatsoever over the `varchar2` type - only disadvantages, the padding and the overhead when increasing its size are two of them.

If you have to increase the size now, you should also modify the column to a varchar so that future changes do not require rewriting the entire table.

You can see the difference with the following test script:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> desc alter_test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER(38)
 SOME_COLUMN                                        CHAR(3)
 SOME_TS                                            TIMESTAMP(6)
 OTHER_DATA                                         NUMBER

SQL> select count(*) from alter_test;

  COUNT(*)
----------
  11520000

SQL> set timing on
SQL> alter table alter_test modify some_column char(5);

Table altered.

Elapsed: 00:01:48.19
SQL> desc alter_test2
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER(38)
 SOME_COLUMN                                        VARCHAR2(3)
 SOME_TS                                            TIMESTAMP(6)
 OTHER_DATA                                         NUMBER

SQL> select count(*) from alter_test2;

  COUNT(*)
----------
  11520000

SQL> alter table alter_test2 modify some_column varchar2(5);

Table altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL>
```

As you can see increasing the size of a `varchar2` takes no time at all (as opposed to over a minute for increasing the `char` type).

So if you want to increase the allowed size for that column without impacting your system, just switch to the sensible `varchar2` type with a new length and forget about the dreaded `char` type.

If you do that, this also is a instantaneous operation:

```
SQL> desc alter_test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER(38)
 SOME_COLUMN                                        CHAR(3)
 SOME_TS                                            TIMESTAMP(6)
 OTHER_DATA                                         NUMBER

SQL> select count(*) from alter_test;

  COUNT(*)
----------
  11520000

SQL> alter table alter_test modify some_column varchar2(5);

Table altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
SQL>
```

---

**Update**

Now changing from the dreaded `char` to the recommended `varchar2` might have implications for your application if that actually expects blank padded values as miracle173 points out. If your application expects `'Y  '` instead of `'Y'` then this might not be something you can easily do (unless you also change the application).

Comment: you are right, it seems that the trailing blanks are stored with the CHAR value. This contradicts the AskTom article I cited in my post. The Change from CHAR(3) to VARCHAR2(5) using modify has some drawbacks. The after changing from CHAR(3) to VARCHAR2(5) the values have still length 3, so they may have trailing blanks. So if you inserted 'Y' bevor the modify command, it is now `'Y  '` if you read it, if you inserted after the modify comman, it will be `'Y'`. So maybe  a reorganisation of the whole table will make more sense.

Comment: @miracle173: that is true, but we don't know what exactly is stored in that column.